# Using ConcurrentHashMap::newKeySet with Android coreLibraryDesugaring

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm attempting to use the new desugaring features in AGP, however I am getting the following error when trying to use `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()` in my app:

```
10-23 21:17:49.471 5023-5023/uk.org.mattford.scoutlink E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: uk.org.mattford.scoutlink, PID: 5023
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method newKeySet()Lj$/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView; in class Lj$/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap; or its super classes (declaration of 'j$.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap' appears in /data/app/uk.org.mattford.scoutlink-1/base.apk:classes3.dex)
        at org.pircbotx.hooks.managers.ThreadedListenerManager.<init>(ThreadedListenerManager.java:49)
        at org.pircbotx.Configuration$Builder.getListenerManager(Configuration.java:884)
        at org.pircbotx.Configuration$Builder.addListener(Configuration.java:726)
        at uk.org.mattford.scoutlink.irc.IRCService.connect(IRCService.java:143)
        at uk.org.mattford.scoutlink.irc.IRCService.onStartCommand(IRCService.java:67)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I have the following in my top level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
    }
}
```

and in my module `build-gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "uk.org.mattford.scoutlink"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {}
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
    compileOptions {
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.30'
    implementation 'org.pircbotx:pircbotx:2.3-SNAPSHOT'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.10'
}
```

Looking at the APK analyser. I can see that `j$.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` is defined in `classes3.dex` but does not include the `newKeySet` method. However `j$.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap` is also defined in `classes4.dex` and does have this method!

The `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet` call I am trying to work around is in the pircbotx dependency. However I have put a call to this method in my Application's `onCreate` method and this also crashes the app.

Thanks in advance for any help. I've been at this for hours now to no avail.

Comment: R8 might be obfuscating that class or method.

Comment: @Martin Zeitler I don't have modification enabled so don't think that would come into play here

Comment: Auto correct. That should have said "minification"

Comment: Thanks for the question/report. I am from the R8/D8 team, and this looks like a bug. I have opened https://b.corp.google.com/issues/171666278, and hope that you can follow up there. I have a few questions: 1) Does both `classes3.dex` and `classes4.dex` only have classes with the `j$` prefix? 2) What happens if you just remove `classes3.dex` (the one missing the method) from the `apk`? 3) Can you share a project with this issue, or a simple example project using the pricboxt dependency demonstrating the issue? 4) can you share the `apk` with the issue?

Comment: And if you can share something that you don't want to share publicly, you can share it with sgjesse@google.com and clementbera@google.com.

Comment: On top of what sgjesse said, could you try to compile your app without pre-native multidex (minSdkVersion 21)? All desugaring happens if below 24 and that will let us know if the problem is related to pre native multidex.

Comment: @sgjesse thanks for the response! Looks like that link requires an internal Google login. Happy to share the APK here though: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j0UAD4os-A3qJw_E2Wg5j-YuYnAgDXEB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: From what I could see one of the dex files contained the j$ classes and also some classes in a `sun.*` namespace, the other contained classes related to my app

Comment: Sorry about the internal link. The external link is https://issuetracker.google.com/171666278. We will take a look at the `apk`.

Comment: Thanks. @clementbera I set minSdkVersion to 21, removed the `androidx.multidex` dependency and changed my Application class to extend `android.app.Application` and I still get the crash on a device with API level 21

Comment: The code for this app is at https://github.com/mattford/scoutlink if that's any help at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a "bug" in D8, it turns out that although the following 3 methods are listed in the docs (https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) as supported, they are not actually currently supported.

This has been raised a feature request but according to the D8 team it is unlikely they will be looked at this quarter. (full discussion of the issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/171666278)

```
public ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView keySet(Object mappedValue)
public static ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView newKeySet()
public static ConcurrentHashMap.KeySetView newKeySet(int initialCapacity)
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved by upgrading the desugaring dependency to 1.2.0 as below:

```
dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.0'
    // or
    // coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.0'

...
}
```

see following information:

- [Desugar libs change log for 1.2.0](https://github.com/google/desugar_jdk_libs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-120-2022-06-21)
- [ConcurrentHashMap (with bug fixes for Android 5.0)](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)